# Malloc, string pointers, and Valgrind

Tags: c, string, malloc, valgrind

My program is like this (**main.c**):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
  char *first="hello ";
  char *second="world!";
  char *seq=(char *)malloc((strlen(first)+1)*sizeof(char));
  strcat(strcpy(seq,first),second);
  printf("%s\n",seq);
  free(seq);
}
```

and I debug with the tool valgrind, it said that($:valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./main):

```
==5118== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
==5118== Copyright (C) 2002-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5118== Using LibVEX rev 1884, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==5118== Copyright (C) 2004-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==5118== Using valgrind-3.4.1, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.
==5118== Copyright (C) 2000-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5118== For more details, rerun with: -v
==5118== 
==5118== Invalid write of size 1
==5118==    at 0x402575B: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484EB: main (main.c:7)
==5118==  Address 0x418a02f is 0 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd
==5118==    at 0x402522D: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484C3: main (main.c:6)
==5118== 
==5118== Invalid write of size 1
==5118==    at 0x4025777: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484EB: main (main.c:7)
==5118==  Address 0x418a034 is 5 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd
==5118==    at 0x402522D: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484C3: main (main.c:6)
==5118== 
==5118== Invalid read of size 1
==5118==    at 0x4025963: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==5118==    by 0x40A0FA4: puts (in /lib/libc-2.10.1.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484F7: main (main.c:8)
==5118==  Address 0x418a02f is 0 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd
==5118==    at 0x402522D: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484C3: main (main.c:6)
==5118== 
==5118== Invalid read of size 1
==5118==    at 0x40ACEFE: _IO_default_xsputn (in /lib/libc-2.10.1.so)
==5118==    by 0x40AA3D0: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (in /lib/libc-2.10.1.so)
==5118==    by 0x40A1020: puts (in /lib/libc-2.10.1.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484F7: main (main.c:8)
==5118==  Address 0x418a02f is 0 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd
==5118==    at 0x402522D: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484C3: main (main.c:6)
hello world!
==5118== 
==5118== ERROR SUMMARY: 17 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 1)
==5118== malloc/free: in use at exit: 7 bytes in 1 blocks.
==5118== malloc/free: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 7 bytes allocated.
==5118== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==5118== searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks.
==5118== checked 47,492 bytes.
==5118== 
==5118== 
==5118== 7 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==5118==    at 0x402522D: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==5118==    by 0x80484C3: main (main.c:6)
==5118== 
==5118== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5118==    definitely lost: 7 bytes in 1 blocks.
==5118==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==5118==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==5118==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
```

Who can tell me why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 char *seq=(char *)malloc((strlen(first)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

You are allocating memory for a string the size of just 'first'.

```
  strcat(strcpy(seq,first),second);
```

And then you try to fit both first and second in it. That's never going to work. `strcat` doesn't create more memory, you need to have included that in the `malloc`.

[There is no need to cast the result of malloc in pure C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

It is also not necessary to do `sizeof(char)`, as that is guaranteed to be 1. Some like to have it there anyway to be explict about the type in case it changes, some consider it clutter.

Comment: there's no need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C; also, `sizeof(char)` is always `1`

Answer (score 3):

Where's the corresponding `free()` for the `malloc()`?

Comment: haha, I lost it, I just want to demonstrate the error of strcpy and strcat. Of course, I should add free(seq); thank you all the same.

Comment: the memory is implicitly free'd by the OS after `main()` returns

Comment: Wow - why do I ever bother calling `free()` then? :-)

Comment: It's worth calling free() at a mid-point in the execution, where the application may need to allocate more memory in the future.  Not at the end of main(), though.

Comment: Its worth it just to have a clean output from valgrind. You wouldn't leave compiler warnings in your code would you?

Comment: @caf Tools like valgrind expect you to free all your memory, or they will report it as a leak. It's just good practice anyway; one day you'll restructure your code and forget all those frees.

Answer (score 2):

You are only allocating enough space for first in seq.

Answer (score 1):

seq is only (strlen(first)+1)*sizeof(char) long, not enough to hold the concatenated string first + second.

Answer (score -1):

I could see that the line :

strcat(strcpy(seq,first),second);

is not wrongly framed. The reason is, you are doing a string concatenation , where you are not giving a proper source. It will work fine, if you seggregate the above syntax into 2 lines.

strcpy(seq,first);
strcat(seq,second);

This is because, when you are doing a string copy, it will copy the string from "first" to "seq". Now, for string concatenation, since it could not find the proper source [ remember that you didnot specifically mentioned that the source is "seq" ], it is giving a invalid write memory leak problem.

Hope this clarifies your question.  Please revert, if any further info is required, for the same.

Comment: Also, as mentioned above,  by others, you need to allocate the proper memory for seq, to store for "second" also.

Comment: `strcpy()` returns its first argument, so `strcat(strcpy(seq, first), scond)` is equivalent to `strcpy(seq, fiest); strcat(seq, second);`.